# How to count instances of string found within files

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to search within all relevant files in a folder.

How can I add the amount of times the string is found in each file so I can return that number?  If it matters, I do know that the string I am searching will only be found once on each line of text.

I have tried a bunch of random things but I get only "1" returned, which I know is false.

```
Sub StringExistsInFile()

    Dim theString As Variant
    Dim path As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim file As TextStream
    Dim line As String

    theString = Userform1.TextBox1.Text
    path = "P:\prg\"
    StrFile = Dir(path & "*.dp")


    Do While StrFile <> ""

        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)

        Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine

            line = file.ReadLine
            If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Userform1.ListBox1.AddItem (StrFile)
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop

        file.Close

        Set file = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing

        StrFile = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code stopped at the first empty line within each file as you looped until `AtEndOfLine`.
Please try this:

```
Sub StringExistsInFile()
    Dim theString As Variant
    Dim path As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim file As TextStream
    Dim line As String        
    Dim amount As Long
    Dim theResult as String

    theString = Userform1.TextBox1.Text
    path = "P:\prg\"
    StrFile = Dir(path & "*.dp")

    Do While StrFile <> ""
        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
        amount = 0
        Do While Not file.AtEndOfStream
            line = file.ReadLine
            If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                amount = amount + 1
            End If
        Loop
        If amount > 0 Then
            Userform1.ListBox1.AddItem (StrFile & ": " & theString & " = " & amount)
        End If
        file.Close
        Set file = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
        StrFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I was relatively close, but I am adding the file name to a listbox just to show the file contained the string. How can I make it say:  Search String (Apple).  Result:  File1, 13. File4, 7. File11, 28.  etc   Where "Apple" was found 13 times in File1 and so on.

Comment: See the last marked line with ###. If you collect those information in a string, then that‘s it, I guess (e. g. totalinfo = totalinfo & “, “ & StrFile & “: “ & amount). As your initial question seems to be answered, please consider to accept it as answer.

Comment: I tried this code modification but I get a strange output of numbers next to the file. I need to add to my listbox only the file name and the total qty found in it.  Example: File1, Apples = 23 File18, Apples = 12 etc.   Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is getting very close to what I want. It seems to work great, but how can I list only the files that contain "Apples" and leave off the ones that don't?

Comment: I added 'If amount > 0 Then'